# Database in Textview

Tags: android, sql

At the moment I am working on info activity where you can find two buttons: *address* button and *info* button.
There's also a *Textview* where the information should be displayed.

> Example: Click on address button -> TextView shows address

My question is, what do I have to enter in the *onClick* Method to realize this?

So far I know how to do that with a *ListView* but not with a *TextView*...

Here my code so far:

```
adresseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override      
 public void onClick(View v) {                  

    myDataBase = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(KLASSEN_SELECT_RAW, null); 

          startManagingCursor(cursor);

    SimpleCursorAdapter sca =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.barinfo_layout, cursor, new String[]
          {"name"}, new int[] {R.id.barinfo_barinfo});

    barinfo.setText((CharSequence) sca);
    }
});
```

Thanks for helping...

Comment: can you explain little more ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a single string out of the info in the cursor. Then set it to the `TextView`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      sb.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
      // do what ever you want here
   }while(moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
barinfo.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I put the db query into that string?

Comment: I edited my answer. Added sample code. May contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your cursor to the first position and grab the text using the appropriate column index:

```
int iColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");

if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    String name = cursor.getString(iColumnIndex);
    barinfo.setText(name);
}
```

no need to close cursor as it's managed